# Enumerate hosts in ansible

Tags: ansible

In the process of the installation of a tool on Linux servers using Ansible, I would like to customize a configuration file with a unique number inside of a cluster.

Imagine a 3-node cluster

```
[mycluster]
machine07
machine08
machine09
```

The configuration is simply a template file customized depending on the machine :

```
- template:
    src: admin.json.j2
    dest: /home/my_user/tool/mytool/admin.json
```

This template contains such dynamic part :

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-{{id_number}}",
...
```

I'd like to find a way to be able to customize correctly this dynamic part like that :

on machine07 :

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-1",
...
```

on machine08

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-2",
...
```

on machine09

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-3",
...
```

How I could do it?

I've tried using a shell script, I'm currently struggling with indexes but I have no many success if it's possible I don't want to create an inventory file for each node, do you have an idea on how I could achieve it?

thank you per advance

Answer (score 2):

I think there could be multiple ways. First way that comes to my mind is using `index()` on the group. I tried this simple playbook:

```
---
- name: test enumerate
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "host-{{ groups['mycluster'].index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

With your inventory it gives:

```
TASK [debug] *********
ok: [machine07] => {
    "msg": "host-0"
}
ok: [machine08] => {
    "msg": "host-1"
}
ok: [machine09] => {
    "msg": "host-2"
}
```

So in your template you can try something like:

```
"contextPath": "/web-interface-{{ groups['mycluster'].index(inventory_hostname) }}",
```

---

A second way would be to use host vars. For example the inventory would be:

```
[mycluster]
machine07 num=1
machine08 num=2
machine09 num=3
```

And in the template you would use:

```
"/web-interface-{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].num }}"
```

That gave the same output as above.

Comment: Oh thank you ! I've never been a big fan of defining variables linked to only one host. so I've used your first idea but I've changed it a little in order to do exactly what I need, please see my comment below

Comment: I don't think that the order is guaranteed so maybe from one execution to another you might not always have the same index. It might not be a problem for your usecase though. But in cas it is a problem, or if you needed some other kind of value you'd probably need a hostvar. It is easy to maintain and there's no magic involved so I think it is clean, but in your case it is up to your preference!

Comment: You're true, if you make a intersec/union of several groups you cannot be sure on how it's intersected, but while you target only one group, the group is understood like a standard array and will index hosts by the order they are been listed in the hosts file. If I had to target several groups I would have certainely use your second case.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the first Rolf's idea with a little change.

Before to download the template to the remote host I set a fact with the desired number.

```
- set_fact:
   id_number: "{{ansible_play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"

- template:
    src: admin.json.j2
    dest: /home/my_user/tool/mytool/admin.json
```

And in the template

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-{{id_number}}",
...
```

So in the end we get a different value depending of the host valuing the index number + 1

on machine07 :

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-1",
...
```

on machine08

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-2",
...
```

on machine09

```
...
"contextPath": "/web-interface-3",
...
```

Thank you !